# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element => vue & laravel... не работает vue

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

code:
app.js

```
    Vue.component('chat-message', require('./components/ChatMessage.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

name.blade.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }} ">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <chat-message></chat-message>
            <chat-log></chat-log>
            <chat-composer></chat-composer>
        </div>

        <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

ChatMessage.vue:

```
    <template lang="html">
        <div>
            <p>message text is here</p>
            <small>author name</small>
        </div>
    </template>



<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>
```

если включить `exemple.vue` работает, а вот если подключить другие компоненты, они не работают.
`app.js` и `bootstap.js` по умолчанию.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Тут судя по всему вы подключаете 3 компонента, `<chat-message></chat-message><chat-log></chat-log><chat-composer></chat-composer>`, а описываете только один `Vue.component('chat-message', require('./components/ChatMessage.vue'));`

Comment: @Orange_shadow решил проблему... npm run watch не выполнялся... а выполнялся с --watch-poll